# Elasticsearch OR query

Tags: elasticsearch, elastica

Can anyone tell me how do I write the below Mysql query in elastisearch

```
Select * from `table` WHERE `Name`='A' OR `Name`='B' order by `rank` DESC
```

I have tried multiple solutions the internet like

```
{

"sort":{"rank":{"order":"desc"}}, 

"query": {

    "query_string" : {
        "fields" : ["Name"],
        "query" : "A OR B"
    }


}
```

and also tried the below code

```
{

"sort":{"rank":{"order":"desc"}}, 

  "query" : {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match_phrase" : {
            "Name" : "A"
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "Name": "B"
          }
        }
      ]

    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: what's your elasticsearch index mapping?

Comment: In general, you can't translate SQL queries to Elasticsearch queries. What's the Elasticsearch query that doesn't work for you? Read http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with Bool-Filter and Order on all Documents:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "filter": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "term": {
            "Name": "A"
          }
        },{
          "term": {
            "Name": "B"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },"sort": [
    {
      "rank": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Or have a subset with Range Query:

```
"query": {
    "range": {
      "JoinDate": {
        "lte": 1431051540
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Do you have defined a mapping?, if so please post it here. How is your indexing document looks like?

Comment: What do you want me to post here, can you please be specific ?

Comment: Thanks. I have mentioned it in previous post. What if you search the term in lowercase (e.g. "Name": "b")? How is your input looks like, or could you give an example of one document you have indexed?

Comment: Thanks. the lowercase thing worked perfectly but how can I add  `"range" : {
                "JoinDate" : {
                   
                   "lte": "1431051540"
                    
                }
            }
    
     }` to the query ?

Comment: Please have a look, I edited previous post. You could change the entirely query like second example.

Answer (score 0):

This is my current mappings are

```
{
    "class": {
        "mappings": {
            "students": {
                "properties": {
                    "Name": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "rank": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "Description": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "Image": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "JoinDate": {
                        "type": "date",
                        "format": "dateOptionalTime"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [Terms filter](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-filter.html). Below is equivalent of SQL query you wrote.

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_search?pretty' -d '{
    "filter": {
        "terms": {
            "Name": ["A", "B"]
        }
    },
    "sort": {
        "rank": {
            "order": "desc"
        }
    }
}'
```